# How to have click or other handler attached to dynamically generated dom in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have form with single text input to which I want to add functionality - on click generate new text input. Here's my code:

HTML

```
<form>
   Fill:
   <input type="text" name="0" class="target"/>
   <br /><br /><br /><input type="submit" value="post it!" />
</form>
```

JS/jQuery

```
<script>
   var i=1;
   $(function(){
     $("input.target:last").on("click", function(){
      $("input.target:last").after("<br /> <input type='text' " +  "name='" + i +"'"  + ' class="target" />');
      i++;
      });
   });
</script>
```

This works fine **but only when clicking on first (non-dynamically) generated input.**
I've checked in Firebug, generated inputs are just fine - they are generated with correct class name and name attribute are incremented as expected - everything fine except click event is not related to any input but the first one, non- dynamically generated.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (in bold): *"Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to `.on()`."*

Comment: @Dominic: `:last` is not a class, it's a pseudo selector. http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use delegated event handler:

```
 $(function(){
    $("form").on("click","input.target:last", function(){
      $(this).after("<br /> <input type='text' " +  "name='" + i +"'"  + ' class="target" />');
         i++;
      });
   });
```

When the second parameter is a selector, the event handler is delegated. [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Works. But I can't think of why in the world i must select parent node ("form") for this. Looks like I'm gonna have to spend more time in the docs. Thanks

Comment: @Miloshio: yes, you should read the docs to understand more, that's just a sample code.

Comment: @Miloshio: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/.